# How to automatically change agent status on Amazon Connect?

Tags: amazon-connect

I need step by step directions on how to load the CCP into a webpage and use the streams API. I would need the javascript to turn the agent from "missed" to "available" after 25 seconds.

Currently we have to manually update staus which doesn't make sense for our use case.

I saw on the Amazon Connect forum someone made mention of a way to automatically change the status of from Missed to Available.

> If you're embedding the CCP and using the Streams API, you can check
>   the agent status on refresh, and if it's in Missed Call, set it to
>   Available. I have this set to happen after 10 seconds.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For an embedded CCP you can do this using Stream API. You can subscribe to the agent refresh status, and do it there.

```
connect.agent(function (agent) {
    logInfoMsg("Subscribing to events for agent " + agent.getName());
    logInfoMsg("Agent is currently in status of " + agent.getStatus().name);
    agent.onRefresh(handleAgentRefresh);
}

function handleAgentRefresh(agent) {
    var status = agent.getStatus().name;
    logInfoEvent("[agent.onRefresh] Agent data refreshed. Agent status is " + status);

    //if status == Missed Call, 
    //    set it to Available after 25 seconds."
    //For example -but maybe this is not the best approach

    if (status == "Missed") { //PLEASE review if "Missed" and "Availble"  are proper codes
        setTimeout(function () {
            agent.setState("Available", {
                success: function () {
                    logInfoEvent(" Agent is now Available");
                },
                failure: function (err) { 
                    logInfoEvent("Couldn't change Agent status to Available. Maybe already in another call?");
                }
            });
            ;
        }, 25000);
    }
}
```

---

If you also need to know how to embed the CCP in a website, you can just do something like this

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<html>
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="amazon-connect-1.4.js"></script>
  </head>
  <!-- Add the call to init() as an onload so it will only run once the page is loaded -->
  <body onload="init()">
    <div id=containerDiv style="width: 400px;height: 800px;"></div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      var instanceURL = "https://my-instance-domain.awsapps.com/connect/ccp-v2/";
      // initialise the streams api
      function init() {
        // initialize the ccp
        connect.core.initCCP(containerDiv, {
          ccpUrl: instanceURL,            // REQUIRED
          loginPopup: true,               // optional, defaults to `true`
          region: "eu-central-1",         // REQUIRED for `CHAT`, optional otherwise
          softphone: {                    // optional
            allowFramedSoftphone: true,   // optional
            disableRingtone: false,       // optional
            ringtoneUrl: "./ringtone.mp3" // optional
           }
         });
      }
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

You can see the documentation for StreamsAPI here https://github.com/amazon-connect/amazon-connect-streams/blob/master/Documentation.md

Comment: Carlos, this is amazing. You are very talented and thoughtful. Thanks for the answer.